# insert array into a column in sqldatabase

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm using `codeigniter`, below is my array. How do I insert the data into a database with column name `sibbling_name` and `sibbling_age`.

I tried a CI tutorial but it showed me an error because 0,1,2 is not field in db. Of course is it how to change that [0] into `'sibbling_name'` column and [0] in `sibblingAge` into `'sibbling_age'` column?

```
[sibblingName] => Array
    (
        [0] => Ryan Yaohari
        [1] => Rico Yaohari
        [2] => Rino Yaohari
    )

[sibblingAge] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => 21
        [2] => 19
    )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you done that works or doesn't work? Show us the code from your relevant model and you're more likely to get help here.

Comment: are `sibblingName` and `sibblingAge` separate arrays?

Comment: yes sibblingName and sibblingAge are seperate arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert), if you want an insert batch you need to use `$this->db->insert_batch();`. But before that you need to properly format your values first.
Consider this example:

```
$sibblingName = array('Ryan Yaohari', 'Rico Yaohari', 'Rino Yaohari');
$sibblingAge = array(23, 21, 19);
$insert_values = array();
for($x = 0, $size = count($sibblingName); $x < $size; $x++) {
    $insert_values[$x] = array(
        'sibbling_name' => $sibblingName[$x],
        'sibbling_age' => $sibblingAge[$x],
    );
}
print_r($insert_values);
// format should be something like this:

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [sibbling_name] => Ryan Yaohari
//             [sibbling_age] => 23
//         )
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [sibbling_name] => Rico Yaohari
//             [sibbling_age] => 21
//         )
//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [sibbling_name] => Rino Yaohari
//             [sibbling_age] => 19
//         )
// )

// and of course in the end, use the insert_batch method.
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $insert_values);
```